# Shared Pref returning wrong value in some high end devices like samsung

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

below is my code for creating shared pref

```
public SaveData(Context con) {
    this.context = con;
    emailSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREF_EMAIL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    emailEdit = emailSharedPreferences.edit();
}
```

for set data

```
public void setData(boolean accepted) {
    emailEdit = emailSharedPreferences.edit();
    emailEdit.putBoolean(KEY, accepted);
    emailEdit.apply();
}
```

for get data

```
public Boolean getData() {
    emailSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREF_EMAIL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return emailSharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY, false);
}
```

At my application launcher screen when i am trying to get data it is returning "true" in some devices.

Now if I have created shared pref by below code

```
 private static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
   // return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
    return  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

}

private static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}
```

For set data

```
public static void setData(Context context,boolean value){
    try {
        getEditor(context).putBoolean(KEY, value).commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for get data

```
 public static boolean getData(Context context){
    try {
        return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(KEY, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

now it is working fine on all devices.
Can someone explain this why this is happening.

Comment: When using commit() the data is immediately written to the storage, when using apply() it is only written to the cache.

Comment: I have used both commit and apply both. but not works for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this

emailEdit.commit();

after this

emailEdit.putBoolean(KEY, accepted);